# NameError: name 'cron' is not defined

Tags: python, volttron

I am trying to create a [VOLTTRON actuator agent](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/main/developing-volttron/developing-agents/agent-development.html?highlight=cron#periodics-and-scheduling) that has a linux CRON like feature to schedule tasks. My experiment is to fire off some generic HTTP requests grequests on a CRON like schedule.

I can create a function in Python like the example states from the link:

```
@Core.schedule(cron('0 1 * * *'))
def cron_function(self):
   print("this is a cron-scheduled function")
```

But I get a `NameError: name 'cron' is not define` Maybe I am missing something where the example from the documentation is missing an import module for using a `cron` feature. Any tips help this is my script in a [Git Gist](https://gist.github.com/bbartling/6fd63cc957f374fc7b871b27de4eb5d7). I think this `cron` service is built into VOLTTRON somehow.

Comment: Have you installed `python-crontab`? That allows you to define the function `cron()`. It's not a Python built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

To have cron defined in a VOLTTRON context import it from volttron.platform.scheduling.

```
from volttron.platform.scheduling import cron
```

https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/main/volttron/platform/scheduling.py#L195